# Microphone in flex/AS

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml, mxmlc

Can any one point me to a small code for testing a microphone which is written in flex/AS

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://renaun.com/blog/2010/04/converting-flex-3-microphone-application-to-flex-4-part-1/

Comment: Could you please update your answer to include the relevant information? Right now the link is dead and thus your answer useless.